# How to create pull request in Bitbucket from Jira transition?

Tags: bitbucket, jira

Our team is accustomed to living in Jira.  The move to bitbucket is new.   And using "Pull requests" will be new.

In this context, the first thing I want to do is have the PR created automatically when an issue transitions from In Progress to Review.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You know there are JIRA Triggers but they work the other way around, i.e., transition issue when a PR involving that issue is created/approved.

In you case I would use a JIRA postfunction that use Bitbucket REST API to create a PR. See here:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Creating-a-pull-request-via-API/qaq-p/123913

Comment: Is this really possible?  I can't see how you would populate the necessary info from the postfunction that the bitbucket create PR API wants to have in JSON.

Comment: You can do it with addon JIRA ScriptRunner.

Comment: could you indicate how?  That'd be an awesome answer to the question!